# BEAM - java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read data

Tags: java, apache-beam

We have a BEAM code with SPARK runner that throws the below error randomly for large files which are in S3 bucket.

Could you please suggest is there any config that is required to overcome this issue.

```
[2020-08-05T05:12:36.410Z] java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read data.
[2020-08-05T05:12:36.410Z]  at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.io.SourceRDD$Bounded$ReaderToIteratorAdapter.tryProduceNext(SourceRDD.java:197)
[2020-08-05T05:12:36.410Z]  at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.io.SourceRDD$Bounded$ReaderToIteratorAdapter.hasNext(SourceRDD.java:238)
[2020-08-05T05:12:36.410Z]  at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:42)


[2020-08-05T05:12:36.410Z] Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
[2020-08-05T05:12:36.410Z]  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
[2020-08-05T05:12:36.410Z]  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
```

Comment: I have this exact problem. For me, I'm trying to read 64 text files which are 5.3 GB each. My application simply tries to count unique lines.

Comment: Yes @Popbones, We havent found a solution for this and we are working on it. Let us know if you have got any fix for this.